# meteor: import directory - modular import of methods which are needed

Tags: javascript, meteor, import, module, ecmascript-6

I'm migrating my meteor application to the import-function of meteor 1.3.

But I think this is not quite the best way it should be done. Isn't it possible to load/import just the method which is really needed?
I mean, right now just all methods are loaded by importing the the *methods.js*. But I would like to do that in a modular way. So if the form `.fomNewElement` is used in the app, the method `insertArticle` will be imported and so on. Not just loading everything...

Below you can see my folder structure for `/imports` and some content of the files. Is there anything more I could improve in the structure itself?

Also it would be great if the import would depend on user roles. Is this possible?

**imports/api/article/client/article.js**

```
import { Articles } from '../';
import { insertArticle, updateArticle } from '../methods.js';

Template.Articles.helpers({
    // some helpers
});
Template.Artilces.onCreated(function() {
    // some code
});
Template.Artilces.onRendered(function() {
    // some code
});
Template.Articles.events({
    'submit .formNewElement': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var title = event.target.title.value.trim();
        insertArticle.call({ 
            title: title
        });
    },
    'click .anything': function() {}
});
```

As you can see, I put into that js-file all helpers, events and onCreated/onRendered code. Hope this is 'correct'... Please give me some hint, if this isn't very smart.

**imports/api/article/index.js**

```
export const Articles = new Mongo.Collection('articles');
```

**imports/api/article/methods.js**

```
import { Articles } from './';

export const insertArticle = new ValidatedMethod({
        name: 'article.insert',
        validate: new SimpleSchema({
            title: { type: String }
    }).validator(),
    run( document ) {
        Articles.insert( document );
    }
});

export const updateArticle = new ValidatedMethod({
        name: 'article.update',
        validate: new SimpleSchema({
            _id:                { type: String },
            'update.title':     { type: String }
    }).validator(),
    run( { _id, update } ) {
        Articles.update( _id, { $set: update } );
    }
});
```

And the other files:

**imports/startup/client/index.js**

```
import '../../api/redactor-article/client';
```

**imports/startup/server/index.js**

```
import '../../api/redactor-article/server/publications.js';
import '../../api/redactor-article/methods.js';
```

**imports/api/article/client/index.js**

```
import './article.html';
import './article.sass';
import './article.js';
```

**Filestructure**

```
/imports
    /api
        /article
            /client
                article.html
                article.js
                article.sass
                index.js
            /server
                publications.js
        index.js
        methods.js
```

---

**Update**

Maybe it would be a better way to structure an import module like this:

```
imports/
    api/
        articles/
            publication.js
            methods.js
            collection.js
    ui/
        articles/
            article.html
            article.css
            article.js     // contains helpers, events and onCreated/onRendered
```

Then I have to import the files in `startup/client` (-> all ui files of this module AND all api files) and `startup/server` (-> just all api files)...

Right?

Comment: The new structure looks good to me

Comment: What you are looking for is called *tree shaking*. Advanced module bundlers like [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org/) can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

- You've put everything under `imports/api`. That directory is designed for collections, methods, helpers, 'business logic' and public API (e.g. if you expose a REST API, you'd do it from within that directory). Use `imports/ui` for your templates (including their styles and associated `.js` files).
- You don't need to differentiate between `client` and `server` directories within imports. Just import the files you need from the respective main entry points (i.e. `client/main.js` and `server/main.js`). This point is a little more complex than I suggest here, see the link to 'structure' in the Meteor Guide, below.
- `index.js` doesn't seem like a logical place to put your `Articles` collection. I'd make a file at `/imports/api/articles/articles.js` for it. See http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html for a good overview about where to put things and why.
- Also, in the interests of following best-practices, use a default export for your `Articles` collection: http://guide.meteor.com/code-style.html#collections

To answer your question about how much of the file is exported (i.e. which functions), there's not much you can do about everything being loaded. The bundler needs to read the entire JS file anyway (imagine you exported an object and then changed it further down in the same file– not the best practice, but possible). If you're not using a function though, by all means, don't import it! And you can always split up your methods into seperate files if they get unmanageable.

Regarding your question about only importing bits for certain user roles: always avoid using `import`s or other types of obfuscation for security. The ideal way to do security on Meteor is to assume ANYTHING is accessible on the client (it pretty much is) and code your server-side code accordingly. That means, if you have an admin area, assume that anyone can access it. You can do checks in server `methods` and `publications` for `this.userId` and do a database lookup *there* to ensure the user has the correct privileges. Again, the guide has more info about this: http://guide.meteor.com/security.html

A final note about imports/exports: the idea behind them is not to reduce code size, but to provide a graph of what is actually being used (and leaving out the files that aren't) to make hot code reloading faster for a better development experience. They also make for cleaner application code that is easier to understand, because you don't have random magical globals swimming around that could have come from anywhere, and help to keep logically distinct pieces of code separate.

Best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks. Just some questions to your answer: 1. I think I don't understand the difference between `api` and `ui` folder. If I put helpers in `api` and templates in `ui`, it is harder for coding, as they belongs together, but are stored in two locations...?? And you say 'associated .js files' goes to `ui`.. 2. 'use a default export' -> Didn't I do that in 'imports/api/article/index.js'?

Comment: I divided the `api/<name>/` folder into client/server, as it is described in that way here: https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/understanding-the-imports-directory/#tmc-importsapi

Comment: it may be 'harder' but it can simplify the process of swapping out bits of your application when technologies change. the idea is that while you may be using Blaze for your templating now, you might switch to React or Angular later. On the same note you may decide to switch from MongoDB to another database stack. The data should be independent of the view, and each should be independently testable.

Comment: Regarding your second comment: At the end of the day you can split up the folders however you like. For your own benefit though I'd suggest it doesn't make sense is to put UI code in the API directory. On the same token it is not recommended to take the Meteor 1.3 structure of `/client` `/server` `/both` and just dump it into the `/imports/api` directory. If anything, put it in `/imports/client` `/imports/server` etc, but there are good reasons not to do this, as laid out in the Meteor Guide sections I linked to in my answer

Comment: About the exports, you are exporting Articles like this: `export const Articles = new Mongo.Collection('articles');`. What is recommended in the guide is `export default const Articles = ...` Again, look at the link I posted for rationale behind this